# Telerik RadDiagram TreeLayout not showing in a grid

Tags: silverlight, xaml, telerik, telerik-grid

I am trying to create a graph similar to this one [here](http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#Diagrams/OrgChart)

I have xaml code like this:

```
<Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 4 0 0" Background="White" BorderBrush="#FFD6D4D4" BorderThickness="0 0 1 1">
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderThickness="1 1 0 0" BorderBrush="#D6D6D6" />

                <telerik:RadDiagram x:Name="diagram" GraphSource="{Binding GraphSource}"
                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                            Zoom="{Binding ZoomFactor, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource repGpDataInstance}}" Height="800" />
            </Grid>
        </Border>
```

In my code behind I do the following: (after initializing components ...etc)

```
this.treeLayout.Layout(this.diagram, mymodel.ChildTreeLayoutViewModel.CurrentLayoutSettings);
```

Yet even thought the layout type is set to TreeDown, I get all the nodes on top of each other and I do not see a tree structure. How can I do this the right way? I need a tree structure of the nodes supplied through `ObservableCollection<Object>`

Comment: I have found the Telerik people more than happy to help.  Try http://www.telerik.com/support.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you have two options for such issues:

1. Add Style for the Shapes that sets default Width and Height of the Shapes. If this does not fill well in your scenario:
2. Try invoking the Layout in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.treeLayout.Layout(...)